# Structure Syntax in C (->)

Tags: c, struct, syntax

Why is it that sometimes dot syntax is used to access member variables in a struct but other times `->` is used?  I have been learning some of the C libraries in iOS and while passing structures into functions the arrow syntax seems to be used often.  I gather it has to do with pointers/memory address/ C type stuff, but I'm not sure on what the significance between '.' and'->' is when accessing fields on a struct.

Comment: `->` is used when you have pointer to struct. `.` is used when you have struct object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.` operator is used to access a member of a structure or union. The `->` is defined such that `a->b` where `b` is a structure or union member of `*a` is equal to `(*a).b`. This syntactic sugar exists for convenience because writing `(*a).b` all the time is tedious. Just remember: If `a` is a pointer, use `->`, if it's a structure or union, use `.`.

Some more recent languages (like Go) did away with the distinction, but not having it complicates the compiler as you need to do more complex type-checking to find out how to compile `.` so I guess that's why Ken Thompson didn't do that back then.

Comment: so to make sure i have got it.  are these syntactically correct?

AStruct *structPointer = (AStruct*)someParam; //
structPointer->aMember //
AStruct structVar = *structPointer; //
structVar.aMember //

Comment: hmm it the comments don't seem to let me use the asterisk *

Comment: @AlexanderBollbach Try to escape the asterisk like this: `\*`. Or even better, put your code in backticks: `*(AStruct).someParam`.

Comment: So with a pointer you access members like this: `AStruct *structPointer = (AStruct*)someParam; // structPointer->aMember` but with a direct variable you access members like this:  `AStruct structVar = *structPointer; // structVar.aMember`   is that right?

Comment: @AlexanderBollbach Still somewhat garbled.

Comment: how so? i'm defining a stuck pointer accessing a member with -> and than dereferences it to a local var and than using dot syntax.  what was wrong there?

Comment: Now it's better, I didn't saw your edit. Yes, your notion is correct.